# how to change the domain from dev_bpm to dev_soa_osb in oracle soa

Tags: virtualbox, soa, osb, oracle-soa

Hi I've **installed oracle soa vm suite**.

In that I've configured the domain to **dev_bpm** initially. Everything is fine.

**Now I want to change the domain to dev_soa_osb**.

How should I change the domain.

I'm looking forward for replies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing weblogic domain name is possible with modifying certain files under your domain.

http://chandank.com/application-server/weblogic/how-to-rename-weblogic-domain-name